# How to make Xcode treat files with a .exp extension as resource files?

Tags: xcode

Xcode recognizes the "exp" file extension as source code.

So every time I must drag .exp files from "Compile Sources" to "Copy Bundle Resources" in Build settings. I can't find the setting to change the way Xcode treats files by their extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `.exp` extension is a reserved extension for exports files.
However, the treatment for XCode is described by the file 
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Standard\ file\ types.pbfilespec`.

There you can find the entry:

```
{
    Identifier = sourcecode.exports;
    BasedOn = sourcecode;
    Extensions = (exp);
    UTI = "com.apple.symbol-export";
},
```

If you set the "BasedOn" key to, e.g., `image`, a .exp file will be treated as image.
But be aware that this may break your workflow if you include e.g. assembler source.

Comment: I set the "BasedOn" key to, e.g., image,But  the .exp file is still treated as code..